# How can I emulate a status bar message with CSS?

Tags: css

When you hover over a link, it tells you where the link takes you to. How can I find out the CSS needed to output the same thing?

I guess I'd only need to know the exact color / font style etc that the browser uses to make such a message.

Answer (score 0):

1. The default font and style vary from browser to browser
2. The user might not be using the defaults
3. Why?

You most like want something along the lines of a span or div with the following CSS

```
#fakeStatusBar {
    background: #CCC;
    display: inline-block; 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: the default font and style does vary from browser to browser, this is true. that's why it would be ideal if I could find the default styling for it in the developer tools (but I hardly ever use such a thing; probably a sign that I should more often). I want to cloak links this way (but not for malicious reasons at all)

Comment: You can cloak the link using conventional techniques and it will work in most if not all browsers - not just Chrome. Next time just ask the question you want answered.